# How to check if row value matches corresponding column value

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a data frame which was created by importing several `.csv` files and subsequently merging them all together.

Each of the data frames that I read in all have the column headings on row 8, with some descriptive text in the first seven rows.

This is why the duplicate rows have occurred - because I cannot use the values in row 8 from the first data frame and then discard the first 8 rows from the rest of the data frames (or perhaps I can - I'm sure it's possible).

Ultimately, what I want to happen is this:

```
- Read first .csv into data frame.
- Take values of row 8 to be column names
- Delete the first 8 rows.
- Read all other .csv files in, remove the first 8 rows from each one, and merge them all into the same data frame.
```

I am now faced with a problem where some of the rows will contain the same values as their corresponding column names.

For example, the merged data frame now looks something like this:

```
--------------------------
| Name | Age | MonthBorn |
-------------------------
| Bob  | 23  | September |
| Steve| 45  | June      |
| Name | Age | MonthBorn | # Should be removed
| Sue  | 74  | January   |
| Name | Age | MonthBorn | # Should be removed
| Tracy| 31  | February  |
--------------------------
```

The trouble is that the combined data frame is almost 340,000 rows deep so I can't go through manually and check everything by hand.  Also, I have a rough idea where each row might appear, but I can't be certain as there is a chance of variation.

How can I either check to see if the value of a row/cell matches the corresponding column name or set up the import process as outlined (bulleted) above?

Comment: How did you wind up with such a merged data.frame? Seems like those headers were improperly imported in the first place. It's better to give a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to show what's really going on. Probably better to prevent the problem in the first place than fix it down stream.

Comment: @d.b I did set `header = TRUE`.  Each file is a snippet of a larger whole, each with it's own set of (identical) headers, and which was extracted from an online database (the export process automatically limits .csv sizes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data frame looks approximately as follows:

```
Df <- Data.frame(Name, Age, MonthBorn)
```

Then you could use an ifelse statement to test if "MonthBorn" shows up in a row.

```
Df$MonthBornTest <- ifelse(Df$MonthBorn == “MonthBorn”, “True”, “False”}
```

Then you should be able to do this to remove the rows that contain True, effectively dropping the rows you don't want anymore.

```
Df <- Df[!(Df$MonthBornTest == “True”), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Your data

```
df <- structure(list(Name_ = c("Bob", "Steve", "Bob", "Name", "Sue", 
"Name", "Tracy"), `_Age_` = c("23", "45", "23", "Age", "74", 
"Age", "31"), `_MonthBorn` = c("September", "June", "September", 
"MonthBorn", "January", "MonthBorn", "February")), .Names = c("Name_", 
"_Age_", "_MonthBorn"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

#### solution

```
library(stringr)
df[!sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) all(mapply(function(x,y) str_detect(x,y), colnames(df), df[x,]))),]
```

#### Output

```
   Name_ _Age_ _MonthBorn
1:   Bob    23  September
2: Steve    45       June
3:   Bob    23  September
4:   Sue    74    January
5: Tracy    31   February
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I believe OP will want to filter this out as well, but OP can correct me if I'm mistaken

Comment: I've edited my answer to handle *rows will contain the same values as their corresponding column names*

Answer (score 1):

We can use functions from `dplyr` and `tidyr` to combine the content of all columns together. After that, filter out those that are the same as the combine column names. `dt2` is the final output.

```
# Create example data
dt <- read.table(text = "Name Age MonthBorn
Bob 23 September
Steve 45 June 
Bob 23 September
Name Age MonthBorn
Sue 74 January
Name Age MonthBorn
Tracy 31 February",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Load package
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Process the data
dt2 <- dt %>%
  unite(ColName, everything(), sep = ", ", remove = FALSE) %>%
  filter(ColName != toString(colnames(dt))) %>%
  select(-ColName)

dt2
   Name Age MonthBorn
1   Bob  23 September
2 Steve  45      June
3   Bob  23 September
4   Sue  74   January
5 Tracy  31  February
```